# Express js router post body in custom module

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am creating REST API endpoints in Node.js as a separate custom module. 
In my module using the express router, I had created all API's.

Then I had included this custom module in Node.js application.

While I am calling get with parameters, in those routers I can able to see those parameter values

But while doing post request I am not able to get POST body which is in JSON format.

Custom Module

### 1. index.js:-

```
module.exports = function(app){

        var express = require('express');
        var router = express.Router();
        var user = require('./lib/user')(router);
        app.use("/user", user);
    };
```

### 2. lib/user.js:-

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
           console.log(req.body);
    };

    return router;
};
```

### Nodejs applicaiton:-

server.js file have below code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var multer  = require('multer');

var app = express();

require('custommodule')(app);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public/views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
app.post('/test/create', function(req, res) {
           console.log(req.body);
    };
```

Then, when I do POST request to http://localhost:3000/user/create with JSON body,
inside user.js logs are displaying undefined for req.body. But if I do below POST call then req.body is displaying.

http://localhost:3000/test/create

How can i get the req.body inside lib\user.js?

Comment: Are you using postman or something? Make sure that if you use the raw tab, you also send the header **Content-type: application/json**

Answer (score 0):

You have passsed `app` to your custom module before mounting `body-parser` middleware on it. so it doesn't know how to populate `req.body`. so move:

```
require('custommodule')(app);
```

after all your `app.use`; or at least after these two lines:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

which are responsible for populating `req.body` with incoming post bodies.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did as you said. Now It is working.